# Check range of IP address using javascript reqular expression only

Tags: javascript, regex, ip

I want to check the range of ip address  in a regular expression ,
I was using this way and it's working so successfully

```
function validate_ip(ip)
{
       // See if x looks like an IP address using our "almost IP regex".
    var regex = /^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/;
    var match = regex.exec(ip);
    if (!match) return false;
    // Additional code to check that the octets aren't greater than 255:
    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        if (parseInt(match[i]) > 255) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

now i want to perform checking of the range and the syntax in just regular expression 
can this be done ?

Comment: Yes, it could be done with regex - but why would you ever do that?

Comment: Yes you could, but it would be *far* from pretty.

Comment: I know but I have to check url contains ip 
http://192.168.0.137/sss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to look at the different cases:

```
25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?
```

This will match numbers between 0 and 255, disallowing prefixed zeroes such as: 055.

If you want to exclude zero:

```
25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d?
```

Comment: The latter one would allow `00`, seems you need `[1-9]\d?|1\d\d`

Comment: thanks , it's working but neither the first or the second accepts zero before numbers e.g.055 
give it a try pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Comment: @Sally I don't know what you tried, but it works just fine on that site. Are you aware that both Bergi's and my RegEx only match *exactly one* number?

Answer (score 2):

The regex for digits representing numbers from 1 to 255 would look like this:

```
/[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]/
// next try, allowing 0:
/[1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/
```

I think you will admit that using `parseInt` is much more readable, less errorprone and better maintainable.

It even could be shorter:

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}$/.test(ip) && ip.split(".").every(function(octet) {
    return parseInt(octet, 10) < 256;
});
```

(using ES5 [`every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), might need a shim for legacy browsers)

Comment: Shouldn't `\{1,3}` be `\d{1,3}`?

Comment: I tried your both regular expression and it only accepts tow digit numbers like 23.23.23.23  and any three digits number like 255 can not be matched 
give it a try ! http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Answer (score 0):

May late but, some one could try:

**Example of valid IP address**

```
115.42.150.37
192.168.0.1
110.234.52.124
```

**Example of INVALID IP address**

```
    210.110 – must have 4 octets
    255 – must have 4 octets
    y.y.y.y – only digit has allowed
    255.0.0.y – only digit has allowed
    666.10.10.20 – digit must between [0-255]
    4444.11.11.11 – digit must between [0-255]
    33.3333.33.3 – digit must between [0-255]
```

**JavaScript code to validate an IP address**

```
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress)   
{  
 if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ipaddress))  
  {  
    return (true)  
  }  
alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")  
return (false)  
}
```